# next.js clicking link on page prompts getServerSideProps, but does not refresh component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js app with a page that is server side rendered. The page displays a series of links. Clicking on one of those links should take you to the same page with different parameters and a different URL. Right now, loading on any URL works as expected. However, clicking on one of the links alters the URL and prompts the getServerSideProps function to get the data for that URL. However, the component does not refresh despite the props being sent to it changing.

Here is the page ...

```
/*

    This page displays a "tag" in storygraf. This component fetches all 
    items with a primary key of "PTAG<PTAGID>". This will be the data 
    for the tag in question, all direct child tags, and all direct article
    children as well as any embedded tags, imported tags, or accumulated 
    items. It then calls children components to display the information.
    
*/

// React and Next items
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// Bootstrap items
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

// My components
import Layout from "../../../../components/layout";
import TagInfo from "./TagInfo";
import TagList from "../../../../components/TagList";
import ArticleLine from "../../../../components/ArticleLine";

// API functions
import { getFullTagData } from "../../../../utils/api/tag";
import { updateTag } from "../../../../utils/api/tag";

// Utility functions
import {
  checkChildTagProperties,
  syncCumulativeValues,
} from "../../../../utils/tags";
import { updateCumulative } from "../../../../utils/api/cumulative";
import { setLatestItems } from "../../../../utils/tagLatestItems";

// Contexts
import { useUser } from "../../../../Contexts/UserContext";

const Tag = ({ thisTag, childTags, childItems, cumulatives }) => {
  console.log("...Loading");
  console.log(thisTag);
  const userData = useUser();
  const [stateTag, setStateTag] = useState(thisTag);
  const [stateTags, setStateTags] = useState(childTags);
  const [stateItems, setStateItems] = useState(childItems);

  const addChildItem = (newItem) => {
    setStateItems([...stateItems, newItem]);
    setLatestItems(stateTag, newItem, stateTag.parent_tag_id);
  };

  const addChildTag = (newTag) => {
    setStateTags([...stateTags, newTag]);
  };

  const handleShowEditArticle = (status, newArticle) => {
    setCurrentArticle(newArticle);
    setShowEditArticle(status);
  };

  const handleShowDeleteItem = (status, item) => {
    setCurrentArticle(item);
    setShowDeleteItem(status);
  };

  // When the page loads, run code to check the child tag properties
  useEffect(() => {
    checkChildTagProperties(stateTag, stateTags, updateTag);
    syncCumulativeValues(
      stateTag,
      stateTags,
      stateItems,
      cumulatives,
      updateTag,
      updateCumulative
    );
    setLatestItems(stateTag.id, stateItems, stateTag.parent_tag_id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={{ span: 12 }} md={{ span: 10, offset: 1 }}>
            <TagInfo
              tag={stateTag}
              cumulatives={cumulatives}
              userData={userData || {}}
              addChildItem={addChildItem}
              addChildTag={addChildTag}
              setThisTag={setStateTag}
            />

            <Row className="accent-top">
              <Col className="mt-3">
                {stateTags.length > 0 && <TagList tags={stateTags} />}
              </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Col className="mt-3">
                {stateItems
                  .sort((a, b) =>
                    a.itemDate < b.item_date
                      ? 1
                      : b.itemDate < a.itemDate
                      ? -1
                      : 0
                  )
                  .map((article, i) => (
                    <ArticleLine
                      article={article}
                      parentTag={stateTag}
                      key={`article${i}`}
                      handleShowEditArticle={handleShowEditArticle}
                      handleShowDeleteItem={handleShowDeleteItem}
                    />
                  ))}
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log("In get server side props");
  const { pTagId, tagId } = context.params;
  const response = await getFullTagData(pTagId, tagId);
  const thisTag = await response[0].json();
  const childTags = await response[1].json();
  const childItems = await response[2].json();
  const cumulatives = await response[3].json();
  console.log(thisTag);
  return {
    props: {
      thisTag,
      childTags: childTags.Items || [],
      childItems: childItems.Items || [],
      cumulatives: cumulatives.Items || [],
    },
  };
}

export default Tag;
```

When a link from  is clicked, I see the console log for "In get server side props" fire and I see the updated results for "thisTag". However, I don't see the subsequent "...Loading".

For reference, here is the component that contains the actual link.

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import styles from "./styles.module.css";

const Tag = ({ tag = {} }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Link
        href="/Tag/[pTagId]/[tagId]"
        as={`/Tag/${tag.parent_tag_id}/${tag.id}`}
      >
        <div
          className={styles.TagBlock}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: tag.data.tagColor,
            color: tag.data.textColor,
          }}
        >
          <div className={styles.TagInner}>
            {tag.data?.tagName}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tag;
```